# Не работает валидация checkbox на js

Tags: javascript

подскажите как исправить проблему с Валидацией, checkbox'а
Прикладываю код: Код выложил полностью так-как мог не заметить ошибки:
Результат должен быть такой что бы checkbox подсвечивался красным цветом, т.е outline
Ну или как имя и email. Вроде бы все указал

```js
"use strict"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

    async function formSend(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const error = formValidate(form);

        if (error === 0) {

        } else{
            alert('Заполните обязательные поля');
        }

    }


    function formValidate(form) {
        let error = 0;
        let formReq = document.querySelectorAll('._zxc');

        for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
            const input = formReq[index];
            formRemoveError(input);

            if (input.classList.contains('_email')) {
                if (emailTest(input)) {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            } else if (input.getAttribute("type") === 'checkbox' && input.checkbox === false) {
                formAddError(input)
                error++;
            } else {
                if (input.value === '') {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            }
        }
        return error;
    }

    function formAddError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.add('_error');
        input.classList.add('_error');
    }

    function formRemoveError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error');
        input.classList.remove('_error');
    }

    //Функция проверки E-mail
    function emailTest(input) {
        const re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@(\w+[\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/
        return !re.test(input.value);
    }

        
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: grey;
}

.form {
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    
}

.form {
    outline: none;
}


.form__title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.form__item {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.form__label {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.form__input {
    height: 50px;
    /* padding: 0 20px; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.form__input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px aquamarine;
}

.form__input._error {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px red;
}


textarea.form__input {
    min-height: 120px;
    resize: vertical;
    padding: 20px;
}

.options {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.options__item {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.options__input {
    display: none;
}

.options__input:checked + .options__label::after {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.options__label {
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 140%;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.options__label::before {
    content: "";
    align-self: flex-start;
    flex: 0 0 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0 ;
}

.options__label::after {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #77608d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
}


.file__item {
    position: relative;
}

.file__input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file__button {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #77608d;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.file__prewiew {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.file__prewiew img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.checkbox {

}

.checkbox .checkbox__label::before._error {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px red;
}

.checkbox__input {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox__input:checked + .checkbox__label::after {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.checkbox__label {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 140%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox__label::before {
    content: "";
    align-self: flex-start;
    flex: 0 0 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.checkbox__label::after {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 14px;
    background-color: #1b6f7e;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox__label a{
    color: #1b6f7e;
    
}

.form__button {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 60px;
    background-color: #1b6f7e;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #0c3138;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;

}

.form__button:hover {
    background-color: #1b525c;
}

.form__button:active {
    top: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0 #0c3138;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form">
            <form action="#" id="form" class="form__body">
                <h1 class="form__title">Отправка данных на почту</h1>
                <div class="form__item">
                    <label for="formName" class="form__label">Имя:</label>
                    <input id="formName" type="text" name="name" class="form__input _zxc">
                </div>
                <div class="form__item">
                    <label for="formEmail" class="form__label">E-mail:</label>
                    <input id="formEmail" type="text" name="email" class="form__input _zxc _email">
                </div>

                <div class="form__item">
                   <div class="form__label">Левша или Правша</div>
                   <div class="options">
                       <div class="options__item">
                           <input id="formRightHanded" checked type="radio" value="right" name="hand" class="options__input">
                           <label for="formRightHanded" class="options__label">Правша</label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="options__item">
                        <input id="formLeftHanded" type="radio" value="left" name="hand" class="options__input">
                        <label for="formLeftHanded" class="options__label">Правша</label>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form__item">
                    <label for="formMessage" class="form__label">Сообщение:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="formMessage" class="form__input"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form__item">
                    <div class="form__label">Возраст:</div>
                    <!-- Ебанутый слайдер выбора Ajax + JS + CSS -->
                    <select name="age" class="select">
                        <option disabled>Выбрать</option>
                        <option value="От 18 до 25" selected="selected"> Молодой</option>
                        <option value="От 25 до 45">Старый</option>
                        <option value="От 45 и выше">Дед</option>
                    </select>
                    <!-- Конец Ебанутого слайдера -->
                </div>

                <div class="form__item">
                    <div class="form__label">Прикрепить Фото</div>
                    <div class="file">
                        <div class="file__item">
                            <input id="formImage" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" type="file" name="image" class="file__input">
                            <div class="file__button">Выбрать</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="file__preview"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form__item">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="formAgreement" checked type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input _zxc">
                        <label for="formAgreement" class="checkbox__label"><span>Я даю свое согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствие с <a href="#">Условием</a></span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="form__button">Отправить</button>
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>


    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/select.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//input.checkbox === false
!input.checked

<div class="checkbox form__input">
```

Comment: Ну одно слово,  Гений, целый день читал документацию, никак не видел ошибки, еще очень много нужно выучить, спасибо что такие люди как вы можете помочь, не дает опускать руки, огромная благодарность, все замечательно работает

Comment: @Qsnakes Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.